# Replace dataframe values by another data frame where username are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

```
>>> old_data_df
    username  loan_balance  age
0  username1            10   18
1  username7            14    8
```

and

```
>>> new_data_df
    username  loan_balance
0  username1             1
1  username2             4
```

I want to replace the values of `loan balance` of `old_data_df` by the values of `new_data_df` where:

`old_data_df['username'] == new_data_df['username']`

The desired outcome would be:

```
>>> old_data_df
    username  loan_balance  age
0  username1            1   18
1  username7            14    8
```

What would be a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update using map

```
#set_index to uername in new_df and then map loan_balance value
old_df['loan_balance'] = (old_df['username'].
                          map(new_df.set_index(['username'])['loan_balance']))
old_df
```

```
username    loan_balance    age
0   username1   1   18
```

alternately,
if you only want to update balance when value exists in new_df

```
#using mask check if mapping exists
# if so, update, else leave value as is

old_df['loan_balance'] = old_df['loan_balance'].mask(
    (old_df['username'].map(new_df.set_index(['username'])['loan_balance'])).notna(),
    (old_df['username'].map(new_df.set_index(['username'])['loan_balance']))
)
old_df
```

Comment: I think there is a small bug when the value exist. Its changing the loan_balance value to the value of the username. `>>> old_df
    username loan_balance  age
0  username1            1   18
1  username7    username7    8`

Comment: solution, update, try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in old_df.iterrows():
    username = row['username']
    try:
        new_loan = new_df.loc[new_df['username'] == username, 'loan'].values[0]
        old_df['loan'].at[index] = new_loan
    except IndexError:  # If username isn't present in new_df
        continue
```